# I need help understanding how to add j-ftp to my project

Tags: java, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

http://sourceforge.net/projects/j-ftp/

I would like to use this in my application, but I am confused as to how to import it into my application and run it.

Answer (score 0):

**I figured it out**
the code they gave made it more complicated then it needed to be.  the code they wanted me to call to run this was code="net.sf.jftp.JFtpApplet"  I changed it to jftp.jar and now it works.  still waiting on a